# App Config Transformation while deploy project using artifacts

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web.config-transform, config-transformation

I'm developing solution with lot of instanses of windows services with **same source code** and **different app.config files**.

Deploy process is based on artifacts. That means i have only *one archive* with *all files* (.dll, .exe,) excluding .config, which copy N times to different folders.

Before (after) deploy i have to modify each .config file, if there any changes, by hand. 
*I want to automate deploy of .config files too. I don't want to modify each .config by hand*. So i thinking about using app.config transformation.

The problem is that transformation of app.config apply at build based on build configuration. For example, if i have Debug and Release configurations, only *one* will be apllyed to config at build.

Is there any way  to prepare all .config files at build or run app.config transformation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use VanillaTransformer which can work independently of build configuration. https://github.com/cezarypiatek/VanillaTransformer